# Mice Imputation Not Working - R Programming

Tags: r, r-mice

I am looking into data imputation with mice, the data set which I am using does have missing data for working with - this is the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DBc_Nc-ehtURx3mGlA477mt5TjVTWTcQ/view?usp=sharing)

The code I am working with looks like this:

```
library(mice)
install.packages("VIM")
library(VIM)

d = read.csv("org_copy.csv")
md.pattern(d)
```

However, this does not seem to work. I have been stuck pondering on this but coming up with nothing. I have looked at the documentation but to no avail.

Any guidance would be much appreciated! Sorry if this is a simple error on my part, just stumped
TIA

Comment: Can you demonstrate what the data looks like and how the result you are getting differs from what you want?

Comment: @sboysel I would expect to be able to plot something using the aggr function within VIM to create this [expected output](https://imgur.com/a/YOehiTe). My output from ```md.pattern``` is simply only the column headers and nothing meaningful.

Comment: what is the dimension of your data, if it is too  big it wont show anything. Try for a subset of rows/columns and see if tt works

Comment: @user20650 when I subset fewer rows it works. Is there a way to subset a data frame based on na data, I know there is only 3 rows with NA data, just cannot think of how to narrow it down the best way

Comment: @AidanDonnelly; I'm unsure what your expected results is but you can find  rows with missing using `complete.cases(d)`, or  columns with missing with `sapply(d, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`. You can use the results from these to subset your data. Alternatively, you can just remove with `na.omit`.